screen tearing ubuntu 24.04
I installed the new version of Ubuntu on my PC and I am having problems with the image when playing videos, whether from my files or on the Internet. Can you help me since that has never happened to me with any distribution?
System report details

Report details

Generated date: 2024-05-06 12:57:09

Hardware information:

Hardware model: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H310M H
Memory: 8.0 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-9400F × 6
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Disk capacity: 1.2TB

Software information:

Firmware version: F20
OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build: (null)
OS Type: 64 bit
GNOME Version: 46
Window system: X11
Kernel version: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic


All I can tell you is that I noticed the same thing, but I don't have a complete fix. Check out the thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2497484

You need to check "Force Full Composition Pipeline" in Nvidia drivers.
NVIDIA Settings (in lower right corner):


Worked for me. In my case I first had to click "Advanced" in the lower right corner. Then "Force Full Composition Pipeline" checkbox becomes visible.
